# Have to open terminal/command line

Tags: samba, gnome-terminal, root

I use ubuntu gnome, it gives error while starting. I have to restart samba with command, but i dont know how to reach terminal before logging in, any advices?

Comment: "it gives error while starting" - it would truly help if you shared the error message with us.

Answer (score 0):

From graphical login, press

```
ctrl-alt-f1
```

Login with your username / password, and run your commands. To log out, press

```
ctrl-d
```

And then

```
ctrl-alt-f7
```

to get back to graphical login.